# Facing error while implementing Firebase in JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting below error for firebase implementing in a javascript project, add data in firebase.
is it possible to use firebase in a pure javascript project?

```
(anonymous) @ fire.js:18
fire.js:26 Uncaught **ReferenceError: database is not defined**
    at myFunction (fire.js:26)
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
```

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="./fire.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    Name: <input type="text" name="" id="data1">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

js code :

```
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "************",
    authDomain: "************",
    databaseURL: "************",
    projectId: "************",
    storageBucket: "************",
    messagingSenderId: "************",
    appId: "************",
    measurementId: "************"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();


function myFunction() {
    var today = new Date();
    var timeStamp = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds() + " " + today.getDate() + "/" + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getFullYear();

    const dbConn = firebase.database().ref();
    var myData = dbConn.child("myData");

    var curr = document.getElementById("data1");

    myData.push({ Data: parseInt(curr.value), Time: timeStamp });
}
```

can someone guide me to solve these issue,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your firebase script tags really defined outside of the html tag?  That doesn't seem right.  The location where they are included makes a difference.

Comment: @DougStevenson 
but I tried with the change of place like in the head also but it is hitting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're missing the [additional scripts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries) that you need to enable the Firebase Firestore library, as mentioned in the TODO at the bottom of your HTML:

```html
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<!-- NOTE: Uncomment the line below -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<!-- Firebase Firestore -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

And your script should be declared *below* the Firebase scripts:

```html
<!-- (Firebase scripts above this comment) -->

<script src="./fire.js"></script>
```

(Sidenote: You should probably move your script declarations to above the `<html>` closing tag to conform to the [HTML 5 specs for the `<script>` tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-scripting.html#the-script-element):)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Scripts can be placed here -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Your document's content -->
  </body>
  <!-- Or here -->
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but for that sturture also I'm facing an issue like database() is not defined. Can i know how to achieve my requirement and push the data in firebase using pure javascript without node_modules   @edric

Comment: Chances are the `database` function is declared on the global `firebase` object, so have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks @edric 
your solution working for me, I haven't added database link in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is executing before firebase is being loaded.

You should wait for "DOMContentLoaded" :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  //firebase is available
});
```

Here is how you could implement it (based on your excerpt):

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "************",
    authDomain: "************",
    databaseURL: "************",
    projectId: "************",
    storageBucket: "************",
    messagingSenderId: "************",
    appId: "************",
    measurementId: "************"
};


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

  // Define your event logic
  document.getElementById("myButton")
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
    
      console.log("Is firebase available ?", firebase ? "Yes" : "No");
      
      //your logic goes here
      
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
      Name: <input type="text" name="" id="data1">
      <button id="myButton">Click me</button>
  </body>

  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
       https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: I tried this but no use, now it is not calling the function also.
@Grégory Bourgin

Comment: From the HTML, you can only call functions if there are in the global scope, you should consider taking the "onclick" event outside of the HTML. See my answer update for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer and updating it, but I'm looking to insert data in firebase and coming to my syntax firebase.database().ref() it is not working, if possible can u plz help to insert data in firebase   @Grégory Bourgin

Comment: This is another question. I suggest you first try to follow tutorials that will teach the basics.